# Remove picture, Restore Picture

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to make a website that has a picture of me, and a button that removes and restores it.  I've got the removal part down.  Now I've tried to start working on the restoration part.

My first over of business was to change the text of the button after its clicked.  It originally says "Remove Picture", but after its clicked its supposed to say "Restore Picture."  But this...just doesn't work.  The image disappears but the text does not change.  Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
<button type="button"  OnClick="remove()" id="me_button">Remove Picture</button>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function remove(){
            document.getElementById("me").style.display = "none";

            //now we need a script that brings the picture back.

             document.getElementbyId("me_button").innerHTML = "Restore Picture";
        }



    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo.

```
getElementbyId
```

is supposed to be

```
getElementById
```

Comment: Oh jeez.  It's always stupid little things like that :/  Thanks

Comment: @DennisMarkham You are welcome :) . Can you please mark it as an answer if it solved your original question so that the post can be resolved.

Comment: How do I do that?